# Excel Limit Cell Input Based On Other Cell's Selection and Work Down Column

Tags: excel, vba

Very new to VBA so unsure where to start. Most questions only refer to individual cells, but I need this to work for all cells in a column and only have them based off the next column's cell in that row.

Column B is a Data List, so based on the selection of a cell in Column B I want the following limitations on the same row's cell in column A:

If B# = Weather Delay Then Error IF A# > 4

Any help is appreciated

Comment: "Weather Delay" is the literal contents of cell Bi? what do you expect to happen with your "Then error"? do you expect a message box to warn the user? highlight the cells? add "ERROR" on Column C? What have you tried?

Comment: If you are looking for a VBA solution then start watching this series:[Excel VBA Introduction Part 1 - Getting Started in the VB Editor](https://www.youtube.com//watch?v=KHO5NIcZAc4&index=1&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5).  It sounds like you want to setup data validation rules.  Here is a list of 44 videos from ExcelIsFun on data validation: [ExcelIsFun](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fyPA9NK1eX0&list=PL0EB55D99E9CF7E13)